# Webpack ts-loader error in node_modules/@types

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

My project compiles fine, but if I checkout in a new directory and try `npm install` then `webpack`, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in /home/nobody/myproject/server/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts
(500,12): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in /home/nobody/myproject/server/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts
(502,12): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in /home/nobody/myproject/server/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts
(504,15): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in /home/nobody/myproject/server/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts
(505,15): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in /home/nobody/myproject/server/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts
(506,15): error TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in /home/nobody/myproject/server/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts
(1002,23): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

and about 25 other errors in the same file, as well as other errors in some of my source files.

In my `tsconfig.json` I exclude `node_modules`, and I also have webpack `externals` set for packaging `node_modules` with a node express backend:

```
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function (x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function (mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });
```

What I don't really get is why everything works fine in my development directory, but if I put it in another one, it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of TypeScript are you using? [The current version of Mongo's `.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/718c4df8f6ad50c15eb0334eb804d3f091c46eef/types/mongodb/index.d.ts#L500) files started using default type arguments, which were released in TypeScript 2.3. There are also something like 20+ default type arguments in the file, which sounds like the number of parse errors you're seeing.

In short, you might need to just upgrade to TypeScript 2.3.

Comment: I'd like to upvote you of roughly a million points, but SO won't let me click more than once...